# About the database on the Ruby

Tags: ruby

Could you help me with a problem? I need to add to the data base:

```
hash = {:date_add => 1 :company => ['test', 'test2', 'test3']}
```

They need to add to pg in this form:

```
 1 test
 1 test2
 1 test3
```

How do I write this in Ruby?

Comment: So you have a database? That should consist of tables. Data would be added to one or more tables. What's the schema for your database?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried? If you haven't, then why not? Your question tells us little that would help us create detailed answers, and instead we can only give you a broad answer, equal to your broad question. To be detailed we'd have to write a tutorial which is off-topic. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. And, instead of using pg directly, I'd recommend using an ORM, such as Sequel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have postgres install and configure, with pg gem (gem install pg) and so on, you could do something like:

```
require 'pg'

begin
    con = PG.connect :dbname => 'testdb', :user => 'postgres'
    con.exec "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS COMPANY"
    con.exec "CREATE TABLE COMPANY(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
        Name VARCHAR(20), Date_int INT)"
    hash = {date_add: 1, company: ['test', 'test2', 'test3']}
    hash[:company].each_with_index do |company, i|
      con.exec "INSERT INTO COMPANY VALUES(#{i+1},#{company}, #{hash[:date_add]})"
    end    
rescue PG::Error => e
    puts e.message 
ensure
    con.close if con
end
```